# HTML Help Workshop on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, chm, html-help, html-help-workshop

Has anyone successfully used MS HTML Help Workshop on Windows 10?

I have run into a problem when I try to compile a package which has not caused any trouble on Window 7 for several years.

On Windows 10, the processing apparently never terminates, although it uses only less than 1% CPU after the first 10-15 minutes. I have to kill the processing. A CHM file is produced, but it can't be opened. The file is twice the traditional size: 1,2GB instead of ~600MB.

Comment: Are you compiling in a network or on a stand-alone PC?

Comment: Please post the results of Help Diagnostics after checking your help environment.

Answer (score 3):

No problems so far with HH on Windows 10. The file size should be nearly the same as compiled on Windows 7.

I'm assuming your old project has been compiled without any problems under Windows 7. And I think you don't have further tools like e.g. RoboHelp in use and compile it the man's way using Microsoft HTML Help Workshop.

I'd recommend using [MJ's Help Diagnostics Version 3.0.5.96](https://www.help-info.de/en/far-html/far-download/#mjs-help-diagnostics). It's a small utility that reports if all the HTML Help runtime & Workshop (compiler) DLLs are installed and registered to the correct locations.  If you have compiler crashes, and crashes when simply opening a CHM, or when searching from the CHM search tab, then this utility will help sort out rouge DLL problems.

Download and unzip the utility to a folder with write permissions. You may have to do a right mouse click to MJsDiag.exe and check `UnBlock`. Run the MJsDiags.exe and generate a report. Important information is highlighted.

If you see errors reported re-run MJsDiags as an administrator and use the "Register Help DLLs" page fix registration errors.